# Localizing bibliography without babelbib

Tags: bibtex, languages

The gist of my problem is that Slovene isn't supported in babelbib. I've got a half-done .bst file which translates some of the needed words, but not all of them. I also noted there exists a slovene.mbs file in miktex. However, when I tried creating a new bibliography style with makebst, I still didn't get the words translated.

Since my bibliography is pretty simple - the only thing I'm missing is translation for 'edition' - I felt it would be best if I edited the existing .bst. How do I go about that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1):

One way of getting a Slovenian-language compatible bibliography style would be with the new Bibulous program, which allows users to customize style files using templates, which are easy to modify. For example, for any bibliography entry of type "article", two template definitions to use might be

```
article = <au>, \enquote{<title>,} <journal> \textbf{<volume>}, ...
          <pages> (<year>).[ <note>]
book = [<au>|<ed)>|], \textit{<title>}, vol.~<volume>] (<publisher>, ...
       <year>)[ Chap.~<chapter>][, pp.~<pages>].[ <note>]
```

Now, I don't know a bit of Slovenian, but according to Google Translate, the English "title" becomes "naslov" in Slovenian. So, if your bibliography database file (.bib file)  has fields like "naslov = {...}", then replacing  in the template with , and so on for any other fields you may want to translate, will do the trick. You would also need to modify the other entrytype templates as well (just start with a default template file and modify piece by piece). You can also replace the entrytypes ("article", "book", etc.) with their corresponding Slovenian forms in both the template definitions and the .bib file.

Of course, to make this all work would also require installing the [bibulous.py](https://github.com/nzhagen/bibulous/blob/master/bibulous.py) file  and running it rather than BibTeX as your backend bibliography processor. The [Bibulous project documentation](https://github.com/nzhagen/bibulous/blob/master/doc/_build/latex/Bibulous.pdf) provides install instructions.

And, as the project maintainer, I'd be glad to help anyone interested in giving it a try.